# Is there a situation in which we need to have an extension method with a default value of an object being extended?

Tags: c#

Is there a situation in which we need to have an extension method with a default value of an object being extended?

For example,

```
public static class util
{
  public static string Foo(this string name="Hello world")
  {
     return name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you have to specify an object when *calling* an extension method (in the extension syntax, rather than just calling the method in its static class)...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Technically, you don't have to. You can use `util.Foo("bar");`.

Comment: @Guillaume - hence the bit in brackets - I was trying to draw the distinction between calling `a.Foo()` and `util.Foo(a)` - but couldn't recall a technical term for the former. I went with "extension syntax".

Comment: Just wonder you use Japanese name I don't know how to mention you on comment?

Comment: @CuongLe: You don't need to use `@ガベージコレクタ` to notify me to the post that belongs to me.

Comment: @CuongLe: [This question and answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2779/19356) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if any such situation will arise, but you can't do that. You will get an error:

> Cannot specify a default value for the 'this' parameter

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile - you can't specify a default value for a `this` parameter.

Even if you *could*, all it would let you do is call `util.Foo()` and have it act on the default value - which could come in handy, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same result with this code:

```
public static string Foo(this string name)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
       return "Hello world";

   return name;
}
```

I believe there are situations where you can apply it. E.g. when you are converting nullable price to string.